# Rails: Deletion not working "No route matches [POST]"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I do not understnad why this is not working correctly. I have a destroy route set and a button to it, but seems to be routing incorrectly and I am not sure what to do.

**app/views/dashboards/show.html.erb**

```
  <% @tweets.each do |tweet| %>
  <p>
    <%= link_to tweet.user.email, tweet.user %>:
    <%= tweet.message %>
    <%= button_to "Delete tweet", tweet_path(tweet), method: :destroy %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

**config/routes.rb**

```
resources :tweets, only: [:create, :destroy]
```

**Error message:**

```
No route matches [POST] "/tweets/7"
```

Answer (score 2):

HTTP method used for `destroy` action is `DELETE`:

```
<%= button_to "Delete tweet", tweet, method: :delete %>
```